# Where can I get feedback on why a question was closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions, feedback

Where can I get feedback on why my question was closed?

The question: [Where can I find jsdom documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379116/where-can-i-find-jsdom-documentation)

I don't necessarily object, but I've asked other similar questions which weren't closed, so I want the feedback to shed light on whether it is inconsistency in the way moderators are making decisions or if I've misunderstood how SO should be used.

Comment: This is the place. Are you in fact looking for feedback, or are you really just asking if this is where you get feedback?

Comment: Also note that SO is a *big* place; lots of questions come in every day. This easily can lead to inconsistencies.

Comment: As for your question, the DOM is a W3C standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/ and those integers are constants defined in that specification. I suspect that a little research effort could have lead you there yourself, and that's why the question was closed.

Comment: @JoshCaswell both

Answer (score 7):

Your question was closed because there's an infinite number of answers. You asked "where can I find?" Well, you can find it *anywhere*, technically. I could go set up some documentation right now on my website and post an answer. Any spammer could post some sort of proxy that just copies content from elsewhere.

The bottom line is, Stack Exchange isn't the place to ask for links to other places. It's a place for asking specific questions that can be answered here. If your question is asking for links, chances are it doesn't belong here.

It's true that many older questions similar to this still exist and may not be closed, but the rules have become more strictly enforced over time and newer questions like this are not acceptable. Oftentimes newer ones like this which aren't closed have merely slipped through the cracks and not received the attention needed to be closed.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing the close reason isn't obvious after having read the FAQ, what you did first was probably the most effective in the general case : politely require in comment the first SO user having voted to close to explain what you did wrong.

What you did afterwards, i.e. coming here to ask again (and get attention to your question) can be effective but I would use this trick with care as it can get painful to see so many *"Why was my question closed ?"* questions.

**Now about what you did wrong and how you could have salvaged your quest for help :**

Your title is a gigantic fail. Never ask *"Where is the doc ?"* or similar, as it generally implies a lack of search and the impossibility to answer in a definite manner. You should have titled your question as something more precise, for example *"How to interpret the nodeType property of a DOM node created by jsdom ?"*.

**Never ask for a link.** Ask for an answer on your specific question.

You could have tried first to edit the question. And after that and after having seriously thought about what failed first, you could have asked a new *different* question.